# update the picture in database

Tags: java

[image]
Hello! I am creating an app for students database. Recently I got a problem when I want to change data that is related to the specific student. Especially problems occur when I want to change the picture for the specific student. I need to check if the picture belongs to the student or not. I store my pictures to the folder if I change the picture, I delete previous one and create a new one. My question about how to check if a picture belongs to the specific student?

I check students in this way.

```
    // get the name of the student from first table getValueTableName

    // get the name of the picture from first table getValueTablePicture

    getValueTableName = jTable1.getModel()
            .getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();

    getValueTablePicture = jTable1.getModel()
            .getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 3).toString();

    File sourceFile = new File(getValueTablePicture);

    setPicture = sourceFile.getName();

    // GET NAME OF THE STUDENT AND THE PICTURE FROM DATABASE AND COMPARE
    // THEM TO THE CURRENT USER
    try {
        CallableStatement statement = null;
        Connection data = getmyConnection();
        statement = data.prepareCall("{call editStudentByName}");

        myResults = statement.executeQuery();

        while (myResults.next()) {
            // COPY PATH IN getEditName
            getEditName = myResults.getString("Name");
            // COPY PATH IN getEditPicture
            getEditPicture = myResults.getString("Picture");

            // add students from database to array
            // mylist.add(getEditName.concat(getEditPicture));
            mylist.add("\n");

        }

        myResults.close();

    } catch (Exception c) {
        c.printStackTrace();
    }

    // I don't know how to move from this point when I check names with loop
    // I check the student with the loop
    for (String person : mylist) {
        if (getValueTableName.concat(sourceFile.getName()).equals(person) == true) {

        }
        System.out.print(getValueTableName.concat(sourceFile.getName())
                .equals(person));
        errors.append(
                "- Please choose another picture or rename it!\n Picture ")
                .append(getEditPicture)
                .append(" is exist for a student " + getEditName)
                .append("\n");
        jTextField3.requestFocusInWindow();
        jTextField3.setText("");

    }
```

Comment: What problems? What are you seeing that's different from what you expect?

Comment: I just want to understand how to check the name of the picture that belongs to the specific user. May you help me?

Comment: So you need to loop over the directory where all the user images are stored and find out which one to update?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I don't know to create this piece of logic. May you start a point how to do it?

Comment: I don't have any problems which one to update. I can't get a solution when the user chooses the same picture as the user who has already reached this picture.

Comment: Please read [ask] and produce a [mcve]

Comment: FYI: *View and Data and File manipulation in the same class... To be able to test you application easily, I sugest to take a look to mvc architecture.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very first thing I'd do is not using separate Strings with strange names like `getEditName` - this is confusing. Consider having POJO (Student.class) and working with that

1. So you want to replace single student picture? Why do you have to iterate some array in this case? You should get single student from database (by Id or via some unique set of attributes).
2. Ok, lets say you have a list of students and you iterate over it. But you still have to change picture for single person so that there is no need to check.
   Simply do

   ```
   String pictureFileName = person.getPicture();//assming getPicture() method returns current picture path
   ```

   and then save new picture with the same name. In this case old picture will be overwritten so that no issue with checks.

UPD:
If you want to check for picture existence you can do the same:

```
String pictureFileName = person.getPicture();
File f = new File(pictureFileName );
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
    // do something, say report warning
}
```

UPD:
If you don't require an ability for students to share same file as a picture it's better to implement this at DB level as well via this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp - so that you simply won't be able to write two different student records with the same picture path field. In this case checks won't matter anymore and you can simply overwrite the picture file because it belongs to single student only

Comment: Thank for the answer. But I want also check if the image exists in the folder. I store my images in the folder. I don't understand how to check if an image related to the specific student.

Comment: Actually, I will get an issue if I overwrite the picture for another student. When I delete one student I also delete the picture from the folder. At this point, I will get an exception.

Comment: Is it possible to have the same picture for more than one student? Is it required? Anyway I think its better not to read all the students into list but use some DB-level check instead like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students WHERE students.picture = 'your_path'` to ensure this picture is used for single student only

Comment: It's possible to have the same picture, but it is not possible to have the same names. I was thinking to check the name of the student and the picture related student. But moving from this point is really hard because I want to check if this picture in the folder and I don't want to overwrite it again for another student. How to move from this point? Any advice?

Comment: Ok. You have to have picture path unique per student. In this case I' recommend to change the database design a bit and add unique constraint to the picture column: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp - this will guarantee you can't write two different student records having the same picture path

Comment: I think, I didn't catch an idea, how to check the picture has already related to another student. Everything works fine when I push the button "View" as you can see on the screenshot and chose another picture for the students. The problem occurs when I choose an existed picture with the same name and saving this in folder.

Comment: Okay. You have student1 with picture say c:\pics\pic1.jpg and student2 with picture c:\pics\pic2.jpg so you want to change student2 avatar to say c:\pics\pic3.jpg. In this case everything is ok because there is no user with pic3.jpg but if you select pic1.jpg for student2 as well as for student1 you break things. Yes?

Comment: so that making picture name column in database unique will prevent writing student2 data into DB in case you already have some other student with the same filename used as a picture. You will have file name distinct across all the students so if you even replace the picture with new one it will affect only one student.

Comment: I add a UNIQUE constraint to the field in my table. I have a question. How to create a boolean check if the picture is not unique and show the message? I think I should get a row from the database and check if the picture unique or not. If not I get an exception.

Comment: UNIQUE constraint will guarantee the distinct during write. If you want to check if none uses the same picture during read I think you should not load all the students into array or list (there might me thousands of students) but use something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students WHERE students.picture = 'your_path'` instead. If picture path is unique count return 1 (or 0 in case there is no students with that picture). Or you can use `SELECT * FROM students WHERE students.picture = 'your_path'` and use the student object for additional check but its redundant

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You helped me to understand the logic part and find a solution.

Comment: Np, happy New Year 2019 :)

Comment: Thanks so much. Happy New Year to you!

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I got my things done. It was a very painful moment, but I got what I wanted. The problem was hidden in a column "Picture" in the table "Student" of my database. First, I add UNIQUE constraint ensures to my column that all values in a column are different. Second, I created two stored procedures:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `checkStudentByPicture`(
in picture_name varchar(100)
)
BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students_center.Student st WHERE st.Picture = picture_name;
END
```

The first procedure checks if my column has unique names and doesn't allow to add the same name to the column.

And I created a second one:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getStudentNameByPicture`(
in name varchar(45),
in pic_name varchar(100)
)
BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students_center.Student st WHERE st.Name = name and st.Picture=pic_name;
END
```

The second procedure checks if the column "Picture" is related to the column "Name". If the column "Picture" is not related, the user doesn't allow to change the name.

Here is the code about checking if my data related to context:

```
private boolean validateFieldEditStudent() {
    StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder(); 

    // call stored procedure checkStudentByPicture                        
    File sourceFile = new File(jTextField3.getText()); 
    String checkStudentName=jTable2.getValueAt(jTable2.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString(); 

    try {
        CallableStatement statement = null;
        Connection data = getmyConnection(); 
        statement = data.prepareCall("{call checkStudentByPicture(?)}");

        statement.setString(1, sourceFile.getName());
        myResults = statement.executeQuery();

        while (myResults.next()) {
            //COPY PATH IN pictureName 
            getPictureCount = myResults.getInt(1);
        }

        myResults.close();
     } catch (Exception c) {
        c.printStackTrace();
     } 
}

// call stored procedure checkStudentByPicture 
try {
    CallableStatement statement = null;
    Connection data = getmyConnection(); 
    statement = data.prepareCall("{call getStudentNameByPicture(?, ?)}");

    statement.setString(1, checkStudentName);
    statement.setString(2, sourceFile.getName());
    myResults = statement.executeQuery();

    while (myResults.next()) {
        //COPY PATH IN pictureName 
        getStudentNameCount = myResults.getInt(1);
    }

    myResults.close();
} catch (Exception c) {
    c.printStackTrace();
}

//check if data is related to the specific user

if(getFileChooserCount > 0) {
       if(getStudentNameCount != 1) {
           if(getPictureCount == 1) {
            errors.append("- Picture "+sourceFile.getName()+" existed in the database!\n");
        jTextField3.setText("");
        jTextField3.requestFocusInWindow();   
        }
    }  
}

 if (errors.length() > 0) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(EditStudent, errors, "Warning!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
            return false;
        }
    return true;
}
```